# Double Key Click Event?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, thinkpad, keyboard-event

My X60T has several buttons designed to be used in tablet mode. To try and optimize the buttons, I was wondering if there is any way to recognize double clicks to trigger a command? They behave just like keyboard keys with two being `esc` and `super L`.

I'm running Manjaro 32 bit with MATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with MATE, and you may be able to bind commands to clicks and double clicks in the window manager that MATE uses. That is normally the preferred solution (and possible e.g. with the `fvwm` window manager).

If the MATE window manager doesn't support it, you can use `xbindkeys` to trigger commands on key/mouse combination. To recognize a double click, you need the "guile" (a scheme dialect) configuration file, an example can be found in

```
xbindkeys --defaults-guile
```